# Animation in Vue.Js not working as expected

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, vuejs3

I am making a card game for my portfolio using Python, Django Rest API and VUE.Js. I have done the logic of the game in python and I used Django Rest API to link it to VUE.Js for animation purposes.
So there are 4 players that receiving 13 cards each.

Example:
`p1. [card1, card2, card3, card4, card5, card6, card7, card8, card9, card10, card11, card12, card13 ] p2. [card1, card2, card3, card4, card5, card6, card7, card8, card9, card10, card11, card12, card13 ] p3. [card1, card2, card3, card4, card5, card6, card7, card8, card9, card10, card11, card12, card13 ] p4. [card1, card2, card3, card4, card5, card6, card7, card8, card9, card10, card11, card12, card13 ]`

Now I have a problem with the animation when it gets to having one card left to play, the animation for the player with the last card it doesn't work. For example, when the last card is played logic behind is that it calculates how many points people did make and give another 13 cards to each player.

`p1. [ ] p2. [ ] p3. [ card ] p4. [ ]`

I consider myself a beginner in this.

I am trying to find a solution for how to animate the last card when it's played as the game will generate other cards to each player after the card is played.

Comment: Your question is unanswerable. Nobody, except you, has a way of knowing how you're animating the elements, what's the logic behind those animations or what's different for the last card of the 4th player. Consider creating a *runnable* [mcve] to allow anyone willing to help to understand the problem. As of now your question doesn't include enough detail to be answered.

Comment: how to ask a good question:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I will construct a new question.